# Can someone help me find the answer to the probability question?

Tags: probability, dice

> A gambler mixed a "cheat" die with all sixes into a box of eight normal dice. She chooses one at random, rolls it twice, and gets six both times. What is the probability that she chose the "cheat" die?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I guess the probability is $81.82\%$

Comment: @callculus nice guess

Comment: @scoopfaze Thanks for your confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

$$P(\text{Cheat die|two sixes}) = P(\text{Cheat die and two sixes}) / P(\text{Two sixes}) = P(\text{Two sixes| cheat die}) * P(\text{Cheat die}) / P(\text{Two Sixes}) = 1 * 1/9 * 1/(8/9 * 1/36 + 1/9 * 1) = 9/11$$ using the law of total probability to evaluate the probability of two sixes.

Comment: Your $1/6$ should be $1/36$, I think.

Comment: You have still a flaw. Please read the exercise again.

Comment: @callculus fixed it

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. I´ve changed my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @callculus thanks; was too quick and didn't check my answer carefully as I should have.

Comment: @StevenWagter thanks for the answer. Shall I confirm the answer as 9/11

Comment: @Lucky1234 if you understand and agree with the solution, you can accept, but this is up to you.

Comment: @StevenWagter could u pls break the steps down for more understanding

Comment: @Lucky1234 I only use basic rules of probability, if you don't understand them you should consult a basic probability textbook.

Answer (score 0):

$P(\text{Cheat Die}) = \frac{1}{9}$

$P(\text{Fair Die}) = \frac{8}{9}$

$P(\text{2 6's/Cheat Die}) = 1\times\frac{1}{9}$

$P(\text{2 6's/Fair Die}) = \frac{1}{36}.\frac{8}{9} = \frac{2}{81}$

Apply Bayes Theorem now to find the $P(\text{Cheat Die/ 2 6's}) = \dfrac{\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{1}{9}+\frac{2}{81}} = \frac{9}{11}$